# Find Gap Date Ranges from two Set of Date Ranges C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datetime, collections

I have  Base date Ranges and Test Date Range. I need to get GAP between base and test meaning  Missing Date Ranges that are in Base but not in Test. what would be the best way to do this?

```
Base Date Ranges
1/1/2012    1/10/2012
1/11/2012   1/25/2012


Test Date Ranges
1/2/2012    1/7/2012
1/8/2012    1/9/2012
1/15/2012   1/30/2012
```

**Output:**

```
Missing Date Ranges that are in Base but not in Test 
1/1/2012    1/2/2012
1/7/2012    1/8/2012
1/9/2012    1/10/2012
1/11/2012   1/15/2012
```

Tried this so far

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        List<DateRanges> aDateRanges = new List<DateRanges>();
        List<DateRanges> bDateRanges = new List<DateRanges>();

        aDateRanges.Add(new DateRanges(new DateTime(2012, 1, 1), new DateTime(2012, 1, 10)));
        aDateRanges.Add(new DateRanges(new DateTime(2012, 1, 11), new DateTime(2012, 1, 25)));


        bDateRanges.Add(new DateRanges(new DateTime(2012, 1, 2), new DateTime(2012, 1, 7)));
        bDateRanges.Add(new DateRanges(new DateTime(2012, 1, 8), new DateTime(2012, 1, 9)));
        bDateRanges.Add(new DateRanges(new DateTime(2012, 1, 15), new DateTime(2012, 1, 30)));

        DisplayDateRanges(GetGaps(aDateRanges, bDateRanges, 0), "Final Gap Fill");
        Console.WriteLine("Completed");
        Console.Read();
    }

    public class DateRanges
    {
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public DateRanges(DateTime Start, DateTime End)
        {
            StartDate = Start;
            EndDate = End;
        }
    }

    public static void DisplayDateRanges(List<DateRanges> dateRanges, string title)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("************************{0}****************************", title);
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "New Recursion");
        foreach (DateRanges br in dateRanges)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start Date {0}   End Date {1}", br.StartDate, br.EndDate);
        }

    }

    public static List<DateRanges> GetGaps(List<DateRanges> aDateRanges, List<DateRanges> bDateRanges, int recursionlevel)
    {
        List<DateRanges> gapFill = new List<DateRanges>();
        List<DateRanges> gapFillTemp = new List<DateRanges>();
        List<DateRanges> bDateRangesTemp = new List<DateRanges>(bDateRanges);
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Recursion Level Id {0} +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++", recursionlevel);
        DisplayDateRanges(aDateRanges, " A Date Ranges ");
        DisplayDateRanges(bDateRanges, " B Date Ranges ");

        foreach (DateRanges br in bDateRanges)
        {
            if (br.StartDate == br.EndDate)
                return gapFill;
            foreach (DateRanges ar in aDateRanges)
            {
                if (ar.StartDate == ar.EndDate)
                    return gapFill;
                if (br.StartDate == ar.StartDate && br.EndDate == ar.EndDate)
                    continue;
                else if (br.StartDate >= ar.StartDate && br.EndDate <= ar.EndDate)
                {
                    gapFillTemp.AddRange(GetGaps(new List<DateRanges> { new DateRanges(ar.StartDate, br.StartDate) }, bDateRangesTemp, recursionlevel + 1));
                    if (gapFillTemp.Count == 0)
                    {
                        //gapFillTemp.Add(new DateRanges(ar.StartDate, br.StartDate));
                    }
                    bDateRangesTemp.AddRange(gapFillTemp);
                    gapFill.AddRange(gapFillTemp);
                    gapFillTemp.Clear();

                    gapFillTemp.AddRange(GetGaps(new List<DateRanges> { new DateRanges(br.EndDate, ar.EndDate) }, bDateRangesTemp, recursionlevel + 1));
                    if (gapFillTemp.Count == 0)
                    {
                       // gapFillTemp.Add(new DateRanges(br.EndDate, ar.EndDate));
                    }
                    bDateRangesTemp.AddRange(gapFillTemp);
                    gapFill.AddRange(gapFillTemp);
                    gapFillTemp.Clear();
                }
                else if (br.StartDate < ar.EndDate && br.EndDate >= ar.EndDate)
                {
                    gapFillTemp.AddRange(GetGaps(new List<DateRanges> { new DateRanges(ar.StartDate, br.StartDate) }, bDateRangesTemp, recursionlevel + 1));
                    if (gapFillTemp.Count == 0)
                    {
                        //gapFillTemp.Add(new DateRanges(ar.StartDate, br.StartDate));
                    }
                    bDateRangesTemp.AddRange(gapFillTemp);
                    gapFill.AddRange(gapFillTemp);
                    gapFillTemp.Clear();
                }

                else if (ar.StartDate >= br.StartDate && ar.StartDate < br.EndDate)
                {
                    gapFillTemp.AddRange(GetGaps(new List<DateRanges> { new DateRanges(br.EndDate, ar.EndDate) }, bDateRangesTemp, recursionlevel + 1));
                    if (gapFillTemp.Count == 0)
                    {
                       // gapFillTemp.Add(new DateRanges(br.EndDate, ar.EndDate));
                    }
                    bDateRangesTemp.AddRange(gapFillTemp);
                    gapFill.AddRange(gapFillTemp);
                    gapFillTemp.Clear();
                }

                else if (ar.StartDate >= br.StartDate && ar.EndDate <= br.EndDate)
                {
                    //     AS----AE
                    //  BS----------BE           
                    //Do Nothing

                }
                else
                {
                    if (AllowedToAdd(bDateRangesTemp, new DateRanges(ar.StartDate, ar.EndDate)))
                    {
                        bDateRangesTemp.Add(new DateRanges(ar.StartDate, ar.EndDate));
                        gapFill.Add(new DateRanges(ar.StartDate, ar.EndDate));
                    }
                }

            }



        }
        return gapFill;
    }


    static bool AllowedToAdd(List<DateRanges> bDateRanges, DateRanges newItem)
    {
        return !bDateRanges.Any(m =>
            (m.StartDate < newItem.StartDate &&
             newItem.StartDate < (m.EndDate))
            ||
            (m.StartDate < (newItem.EndDate) &&
             (newItem.EndDate) <= (m.EndDate))
            ||
            (newItem.StartDate < m.StartDate &&
             m.StartDate < (newItem.EndDate))
            ||
            (newItem.StartDate < (m.EndDate) &&
             (m.EndDate) <= (newItem.EndDate))
            );
    }
```

Comment: Please show code that you have already but feel that it is not "the best" along with direction you want to improve your code. Otherwise likely to be closed soon...

Comment: What have you tried? It seems pretty trivial, just generate the dates first from the ranges, then run Linq Except query, and regenerate the ranges from the resulting dates

Comment: Is pure SQL acceptable? I don't see it in your tags...

Comment: yes sql would be fine too

Comment: Are all your intervals definitely non-overlapping? Might there be some ranges in Base which cover two Test ranges? How about a Test range which uses more than one Base range? More context would be useful.

Comment: What constitutes a gap (i.e. what is your smallest resolution)?  Is it one day?

Comment: there should not be overlap before and after between any ranges

Comment: yes smallest resolution is 1 day

Comment: This was an enjoyable challenge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET) to calculate the gaps:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void GapFinder()
{
  // base periods
  TimePeriodCollection basePeriods = new TimePeriodCollection();
  basePeriods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2012, 1, 1 ), new DateTime( 2012, 1, 10 ) ) );
  basePeriods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2012, 1, 11 ), new DateTime( 2012, 1, 25 ) ) );
  ITimePeriodCollection combinedBasePeriods = new TimePeriodCombiner<TimeRange>().CombinePeriods( basePeriods );

  // test periods
  TimePeriodCollection testPeriods = new TimePeriodCollection();
  testPeriods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2012, 1, 2 ), new DateTime( 2012, 1, 7 ) ) );
  testPeriods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2012, 1, 8 ), new DateTime( 2012, 1, 9 ) ) );
  testPeriods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2012, 1, 15 ), new DateTime( 2012, 1, 30 ) ) );
  ITimePeriodCollection combinedTestPeriods = new TimePeriodCombiner<TimeRange>().CombinePeriods( testPeriods );

  // gaps
  TimePeriodCollection gaps = new TimePeriodCollection();
  foreach ( ITimePeriod basePeriod in combinedBasePeriods )
  {
    gaps.AddAll( new TimeGapCalculator<TimeRange>().GetGaps( combinedTestPeriods, basePeriod ) );
  }
  foreach ( ITimePeriod gap in gaps )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "Gap: " + gap );
  }
} // GapFinder
```

Comment: how do i change this to show me no one day overlap meaning for example above the answer would be 1/1/2012    1/1/2012 and 
1/12/2012   1/14/2012. can the library do this easily?

Answer (score 4):

The following code satisfies the given constraints of the problem:

#### Unit Test

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<DateRange> _base = new[] { new DateRange() { Start = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2012"), End = DateTime.Parse("1/10/2012")},
                                               new DateRange() { Start = DateTime.Parse("1/11/2012"), End = DateTime.Parse("1/25/2012")} };

        IEnumerable<DateRange> _test = new[] { new DateRange() { Start = DateTime.Parse("1/2/2012"), End = DateTime.Parse("1/7/2012")},
                                               new DateRange() { Start = DateTime.Parse("1/8/2012"), End = DateTime.Parse("1/9/2012")},
                                               new DateRange() { Start = DateTime.Parse("1/15/2012"), End = DateTime.Parse("1/30/2012")} };

        IEnumerable<DateRange> _theoreticalGaps = new[] { new DateRange() { Start = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2012"), End = DateTime.Parse("1/2/2012")},
                                               new DateRange() { Start = DateTime.Parse("1/7/2012"), End = DateTime.Parse("1/8/2012")},
                                               new DateRange() { Start = DateTime.Parse("1/9/2012"), End = DateTime.Parse("1/10/2012")},
                                               new DateRange() { Start = DateTime.Parse("1/11/2012"), End = DateTime.Parse("1/15/2012")} };


        var gapsInTestNotInBase = FindGaps(_base, _test);

        Debug.Assert(Enumerable.SequenceEqual(_theoreticalGaps, gapsInTestNotInBase));
    }
```

#### FindGaps Method

```
    public static IEnumerable<DateRange> FindGaps(IEnumerable<DateRange> baseCollection, IEnumerable<DateRange> testCollection)
    {
        var allBaseDates = baseCollection.SelectMany(o => o.GetDiscreetDates())
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(o => o.Ticks);

        var missingInTest = (from d in allBaseDates
                             let inRange = testCollection.Any(o => d.IsInRange(o))
                             where !inRange
                             select d).ToArray();

        var gaps = missingInTest.Select(o => new DateRange() { Start = o, End = o.AddDays(1) });

        gaps = gaps.GroupConsecutive();

        return gaps;

    }
```

#### DateRange Class

```
public class DateRange
{
    protected bool Equals(DateRange other)
    {
        return Start.Equals(other.Start) && End.Equals(other.End);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (Start.GetHashCode()*397) ^ End.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDiscreetDates()
    {
        //Start is not allowed to equal end.
        if (Start.Date == End.Date)
            throw new ArgumentException("Start cannot equal end.");

        var output = new List<DateTime>();

        var current = Start.Date;

        while (current < End.Date) {
            output.Add(current);
            current = current.AddDays(1);
        }

        return output;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((DateRange) obj);
    }
}
```

#### Extension Methods

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsInRange(this DateTime testDate, DateRange range)
    {
        return range.Start <= testDate && range.End > testDate;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DateRange> GroupConsecutive(this IEnumerable<DateRange> input)
    {
        var current = input.ToArray();
        var nextIndex = 0;

        //uses lookahead to figure out if gaps are consecutive.
        for (int i = 0; i < current.Length - 1; i++) {

            //If the next range is consecutive to the current, skip;
            if (!current[i].End.IsInRange(current[i + 1])) {
                yield return new DateRange()
                               {
                                   Start = current[nextIndex].Start,
                                   End = current[i].End
                               };
                nextIndex = i + 1;
            }
        }

        //If the last elements were consecutive, pull out the final item.
        if (nextIndex != current.Length) {
            yield return new DateRange()
            {
                Start = current[nextIndex].Start,
                End = current[current.Length - 1].End
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Extension methods**

```
public static class DateRangeEnumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDates(this IEnumerable<DateRange> source)
    {
        var sortedSource = source.OrderBy(r => r.From);

        foreach (var range in sortedSource)
        {
            var d = range.From;
            while (d < range.To)
            {
                yield return d;
                d = d.AddDays(1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DateRange> GetRanges(this IEnumerable<DateTime> source)
    {
        var sortedSource = source.OrderBy(d => d);
        var enumerator = sortedSource.GetEnumerator();

        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        DateTime from = enumerator.Current;
        DateTime prev = from;

        while (true)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (enumerator.Current == prev.AddDays(1))
                        prev = enumerator.Current;
                    else
                        break;
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return new DateRange() { From = from, To = prev.AddDays(1) };
                    yield break;
                }

            }

            yield return new DateRange() { From = from, To = prev.AddDays(1) };

            from = enumerator.Current;
            prev = enumerator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
var missing = BaseRanges.GetDates().Except(TestRanges.GetDates());
var ranges = missing.GetRanges();
```

I've tested it on your sample data and returns what it should.

Both extension methods are lazy and reads/returns one element at the time.

*I'm pretty sure `GetRanges` method can be made much more readable :)*

Comment: I tested this against my code, it works.  Good job, cool that we both came up with (slightly) different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

this worked too

static void Main(string[] args)
    {

```
    List<DateRanges> aDateRanges = new List<DateRanges>();
    List<DateRanges> bDateRanges = new List<DateRanges>();

    aDateRanges.Add(new DateRanges(new DateTime(2012, 1, 1), new DateTime(2012, 1, 10)));
    aDateRanges.Add(new DateRanges(new DateTime(2012, 1, 11), new DateTime(2012, 1, 25)));


    bDateRanges.Add(new DateRanges(new DateTime(2012, 1, 2), new DateTime(2012, 1, 7)));
    bDateRanges.Add(new DateRanges(new DateTime(2012, 1, 8), new DateTime(2012, 1, 9)));
    bDateRanges.Add(new DateRanges(new DateTime(2012, 1, 15), new DateTime(2012, 1, 30)));

    DisplayDateRanges(GetGaps(aDateRanges, bDateRanges, 0), "Final Gap Fill");
    Console.WriteLine("Completed");
    Console.Read();
}

public class DateRanges
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public DateRanges(DateTime Start, DateTime End)
    {
        StartDate = Start;
        EndDate = End;
    }
}

public static void DisplayDateRanges(List<DateRanges> dateRanges, string title)
{
    Console.WriteLine("************************{0}****************************", title);
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "New Recursion");
    foreach (DateRanges br in dateRanges)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start Date {0}   End Date {1}", br.StartDate, br.EndDate);
    }

}

public static List<DateRanges> GetGaps(List<DateRanges> aDateRanges, List<DateRanges> bDateRanges, int recursionlevel)
{
    List<DateRanges> gapFill = new List<DateRanges>();
    List<DateRanges> gapFillTemp = new List<DateRanges>();
    List<DateRanges> bDateRangesTemp = new List<DateRanges>(bDateRanges);
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Recursion Level Id {0} +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++", recursionlevel);
    DisplayDateRanges(aDateRanges, " A Date Ranges ");
    DisplayDateRanges(bDateRanges, " B Date Ranges ");

    foreach (DateRanges br in bDateRanges)
    {
        if (br.StartDate == br.EndDate)
            return gapFill;
        foreach (DateRanges ar in aDateRanges)
        {
            if (ar.StartDate == ar.EndDate)
                return gapFill;
            if (br.StartDate == ar.StartDate && br.EndDate == ar.EndDate)
                continue;
            else if (br.StartDate >= ar.StartDate && br.EndDate <= ar.EndDate)
            {
                gapFillTemp.AddRange(GetGaps(new List<DateRanges> { new DateRanges(ar.StartDate, br.StartDate) }, bDateRangesTemp, recursionlevel + 1));
                if (gapFillTemp.Count == 0)
                {
                    //gapFillTemp.Add(new DateRanges(ar.StartDate, br.StartDate));
                }
                bDateRangesTemp.AddRange(gapFillTemp);
                gapFill.AddRange(gapFillTemp);
                gapFillTemp.Clear();

                gapFillTemp.AddRange(GetGaps(new List<DateRanges> { new DateRanges(br.EndDate, ar.EndDate) }, bDateRangesTemp, recursionlevel + 1));
                if (gapFillTemp.Count == 0)
                {
                   // gapFillTemp.Add(new DateRanges(br.EndDate, ar.EndDate));
                }
                bDateRangesTemp.AddRange(gapFillTemp);
                gapFill.AddRange(gapFillTemp);
                gapFillTemp.Clear();
            }
            else if (br.StartDate < ar.EndDate && br.EndDate >= ar.EndDate)
            {
                gapFillTemp.AddRange(GetGaps(new List<DateRanges> { new DateRanges(ar.StartDate, br.StartDate) }, bDateRangesTemp, recursionlevel + 1));
                if (gapFillTemp.Count == 0)
                {
                    //gapFillTemp.Add(new DateRanges(ar.StartDate, br.StartDate));
                }
                bDateRangesTemp.AddRange(gapFillTemp);
                gapFill.AddRange(gapFillTemp);
                gapFillTemp.Clear();
            }

            else if (ar.StartDate >= br.StartDate && ar.StartDate < br.EndDate)
            {
                gapFillTemp.AddRange(GetGaps(new List<DateRanges> { new DateRanges(br.EndDate, ar.EndDate) }, bDateRangesTemp, recursionlevel + 1));
                if (gapFillTemp.Count == 0)
                {
                   // gapFillTemp.Add(new DateRanges(br.EndDate, ar.EndDate));
                }
                bDateRangesTemp.AddRange(gapFillTemp);
                gapFill.AddRange(gapFillTemp);
                gapFillTemp.Clear();
            }

            else if (ar.StartDate >= br.StartDate && ar.EndDate <= br.EndDate)
            {
                //     AS----AE
                //  BS----------BE           
                //Do Nothing

            }
            else
            {
                if (AllowedToAdd(bDateRangesTemp, new DateRanges(ar.StartDate, ar.EndDate)))
                {
                    bDateRangesTemp.Add(new DateRanges(ar.StartDate, ar.EndDate));
                    gapFill.Add(new DateRanges(ar.StartDate, ar.EndDate));
                }
            }

        }



    }
    return gapFill;
}


static bool AllowedToAdd(List<DateRanges> bDateRanges, DateRanges newItem)
{
    return !bDateRanges.Any(m =>
        (m.StartDate < newItem.StartDate &&
         newItem.StartDate < (m.EndDate))
        ||
        (m.StartDate < (newItem.EndDate) &&
         (newItem.EndDate) <= (m.EndDate))
        ||
        (newItem.StartDate < m.StartDate &&
         m.StartDate < (newItem.EndDate))
        ||
        (newItem.StartDate < (m.EndDate) &&
         (m.EndDate) <= (newItem.EndDate))
        );
}
```